# option omnifunc is not set in vim?

Tags: vim

```
root@debian:/home/debian# echo  $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib/python2.7/:

root@debian:/home/debian# ls /usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/ 
adacomplete.vim  decada.vim htmlcomplete.vim    netrw.vim        pythoncomplete.vim  spellfile.vim       tohtml.vim       zip.vim
ada.vim      getscript.vim  javascriptcomplete.vim  paste.vim        rcomplete.vim   sqlcomplete.vim     vimball.vim
ccomplete.vim    gnat.vim   netrwFileHandlers.vim   phpcomplete.vim      README.txt      syntaxcomplete.vim  xml
csscomplete.vim  gzip.vim   netrwSettings.vim   python3complete.vim  rubycomplete.vim    tar.vim         xmlcomplete.vim

cat  /etc/vim/vimrc
runtime! debian.vim
set mouse=a     " Enable mouse usage (all modes)
set ts=4
set expandtab 
set shiftwidth=4 
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
set number
set textwidth=80
syntax enable 
filetype indent on
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType python setlocal et sta sw=4 sts=4
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType java set omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
if has("autocmd") && exists("+omnifunc")
     autocmd Filetype *
   \ if &omnifunc == "" |
   \   setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete |
   \ endif
endif
```

when i edit a python file such as the attatchment ,input `ctrl+x` ,output is
attachment1:
[image]

input `ctrl+o` :
[image]

option omnifunc is not set ?which setup is wrong in
my vimrc or else where?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

1. Since you have `filetype plugin indent on` you don't need all those `omnifunc` lines.
2. Your custom settings **have no place in `/etc/vim/vimrc`.** Whatever you have done in `/etc/vim/` *must* be reverted as soon as possible.

   The right place for your settings is `~/.vimrc` and the right place for your plugins is `~/.vim/`.

To make it short, do things normally if you expect Vim to work normally.

Comment: "To make it short, do things normally if you expect Vim to work normally." In what way is this supposed to be helpful ?

Answer (score 6):

Try with an empty setup and no plugins:

```
vim --noplugin -u NONE yourfile.html
```

The error means nothing's set the 'omnifunc' variable in Vim, which is usually done by the filetype plugins.

Try:

```
:set filetype=html
```

Or python, or whatever, and see if `<C-X><C-O>` then works.

Also, try:

```
:set omnifunc
```

And see if it's set to any value.

Comment: I believe the recommended way to start vim without a vimrc is `-u NONE`. 

Using `-u .` throws an error

Comment: As of 2021, yep, appears so, thanks. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where it is placed.
The help  (`:h autocommand`) say that the FileType option is triggered... :

> ```
> FileType       when the 'filetype' option has been set`
> ```

I did some test.
I opened a file and manually set the filetype and the autocommand.

Way that **don't works**

```
:set ft?
   filetype=text

:verbose set omnifunc?
   omnifunc=

:set ft=todo

:au filetype todo set omnifunc=todo#Complete

:verbose set omnifunc?
   omnifunc=
```

So I reversed the order.

Way that **works!**

```
:set ft?
   filetype=text

:verbose set omnifunc?
   omnifunc=

:au filetype todo set omnifunc=todo#Complete

:verbose set omnifunc?
   omnifunc=

:set ft=todo

:verbose set omnifunc?
   omnifunc=todo#Complete
```

So, try to put autocommand with filetype option *before* the row where set the filetype on.